# I cannot save data sent from Arduino Uno to Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4, i2c, sqlite

I am trying to send sensor reading from Arduino Uno to raspberry pi and I want to save this incoming sensor reading to SQLite which I downloaded to Raspberry pi.  I used lm35 sensor on Arduino Uno and i used the i2c way for communication between Arduino Raspberry pi.  I managed to transmit the data from the sensor to the arduino uno and from there to the Raspberry Pi. Then I showed this data in the interface I created with the guizero library on Raspberry Pi. With a button I added, I enabled the temperature data to be updated when the button is pressed. But my shortcoming here was missing the data in between and not being able to see all the data. For this, I decided to download SQLite and save the data here, but no matter how much I searched, I could not be successful. I tried many sample codes but could not adapt any of them against this application. I leave the code used below. I know that I make mistakes from time to time, but no matter how hard I searched, I couldn't find the right one. Is the SQLite I'm using a wrong choice? Any chance of what I'm doing getting fixed and still working? I don't know how to write the code in the marked field, I can't find it either. I'm pretty new to this stuff.  Please help, thanks. (note:The marked place (!!!???) is wrong, but I can't find the correct one.)

```
from guizero import App, Text, PushButton

import smbus
import smbus as SMBus
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime

bus=smbus.SMBus(1)

address= 0x2a

app=App(title="Arduino'dan veri alma")
app.bg="white"
app.fg="black"


#dattabse bağla
conn=sqlite3.connect('deneme1.db')
c=conn.cursor()

#tablo oluşturma
def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablo(unix REAL, tarih REAL, sicaklik REAL)')

#verilerin tabloya yazılması
def dynamic_data_entry():
    unix=int(time.time())
    tarih=str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y,-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    
    sicaklik=address.read_retry(3,5) (!!!???)
    
    c.execute("INSERT INFO tablo (unix, tarih, nem, sicaklik) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (unix, tarih, nem, sicaklik))
    conn.commit()
data = bus.read_byte(address)

def gorev1(n):
    for i in range(0,int(n)):
        dynamic_data_entry()
        time.sleep(1)
        
create_table()
x=input('kaç saniyelik veri kaydedilsin?')
y=input('kaç sn öncesini görmek istersin?')
gorev1(x)

c.close()
conn.close()





def yeni_sicaklik():
     data_display.value=bus.read_byte(address)
      




guncelleme= PushButton(app, command=yeni_sicaklik, text="güncelle")
data_display= Text(app, text="gelen veri:" +str(data))

app.display
```

Comment: Programmers break tasks into steps and solve each step. The alternative is top down design. Either way this is not specific to the Pi.

Comment: So am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Rather than use a database why not just append the sample readings to a file?

Comment: Ask your self these questions; 1. Can you receive data (Arduino is irrelevant) ? 2. Why are you using a GUI for a simple logging task? 3. Why are you using any buttons?

Comment: `no matter how hard I searched, I couldn't find the right one` ... that is not how you write a program

Comment: start very simply ... receive data and print it to the screen ... nothing more ... learn and understand each of the program instructions ............ next, insert some fixed data, like "abc123" or 12345 into a database, read the data from the database and print to screen... nothing else .... again, learn what each program instruction does ........ then try to put the two together

Comment: I have no problem in receiving and printing data. And I put the button for testing purposes. I was able to receive and print data without needing to use it. But as I said, when it comes to saving to the database, I'm stuck.  Finally, as I wrote earlier, I'm new, please forgive my mistakes. From now on, I will try to correct my mistakes by going the right way.

Comment: then, why does your post include info like `I used lm35 sensor on Arduino Uno and i used the i2c way for communication between Arduino Raspberry pi.`? ... it is totally irrelevant ... it has nothing to do with the problem ... please edit your post to focus on the actual problem

Comment: @Cat'sMeow ```c.execute("INSERT INFO tablo``` you want to change that to INSERT INTO